# Is it possible to make the browser stop messing with the font size of headers in articles and sections?

Tags: css, html, header, article

My HTML5 presents a list of bookmarks, like this:

```
    <h1>Bookmarks</h1> <!-- Big text -->
    <ul class='bookmarks-list'>
      <li>
        <article class='bookmark'>
          <h1> <!-- Small text, not desired. :( -->
            <a href='/bookmarks/show/4ed230552357a3f96907fb5f'>Google</a>
          </h1>
          <p>...</p>
        </article>
      </li>
      <li>
        <article class='bookmark'>
          <h1> <!-- Small text, not desired. :( -->
            <a href='/bookmarks/show/4ed235562357a3f96907fb60'>Stack Overflow</a>
          </h1>
          <p>...</p>
        </article>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

The problem is that the `h1` tags in the bookmarks have a smaller `font-size` than the `h1` which is not in an article (the title of the web page for example).

[image: Screenshot.]

I could of course class every `h1` and style it with the same `font-size`, but I would like to style all `h1`s in all levels at once without adding a class to them. Is this possible?

Comment: @Šime Vidas I tried that already, but the result is the same. (All get bigger, but `h1`s inside articles are still smaller than `h1`s not inside articles.)

Comment: Can you post the CSS code that is bound to that web-page?

Comment: @Šime Vidas haha, you were right. I accidentally had an `article h1 {font-size 1.5em;}` in my CSS. I removed it, added what you suggested and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

If you check (for example) Firefox's default stylesheet (try visiting `resource://gre-resources/html.css` in Firefox) you'll see there are rules like this:

```
h2,
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: .83em 0;
}

h3,
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.17em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

An `h1` that appears at one level of nesting has the same default style as `h2`, at two levels of nesting it has the same default as `h3`.  Your problem is that these rules are [more specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) than the rules you are using.  To fix it, write rules which are more specific than those in the default stylesheet (Replico's answer should work, I think), or hack it with `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

is `.bookmark h1` a `{font-size:100px;}` any good to you?